# 2 Different 2d list with different locations, list 1 changes when list 2 is changed

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists, grid and oldgrid. grid is a 3*3 list, and i assigned oldgrid as `oldgrid = grid[:]` as i know this should prevent this sort of issue.

Later in the code, i change an item in the list grid, but when i did this both grid and oldgrid changed. The code i have is

```
print(oldgrid)
print(id(oldgrid),id(grid))
grid[1][1] = 2 
print(oldgrid)
```

which outputs

> [[2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]

> (139716659684608, 139716659609184)

> [[2, 1, 1], [1,**2**, 0], [0, 1, 1]]

Both lists clearly have different locations in storage, (as shown by the print id statement) so how come when grid changes oldgrid changes as well?

Edit: Thanks for the solution, copy.deepcopy() works well.

Comment: Try `print(id(oldgrid[1]), id(grid[1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oldgrid = grid[:]` copies the outer list, but in it, it keeps the inner lists

You need a deep copy

```
oldgrid = copy.deepcopy(grid)
```